# the @property showsIndoorMap is invalid in MAMapView of AMap3DMap Pod

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [MAMapServices sharedServices].apiKey = @"xxx";
        self.mapView = [[MAMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds))];
        self.mapView.delegate = self;
        self.mapView.showsIndoorMap = YES;
        self.mapView.showsCompass = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
    }
```

I use the code above to show the map in my app. I want to use  "self.mapView.showsIndoorMap = YES;" to show the indoor map but it failed. How can i see the indoor map ?

Comment: How about you tell us what `MAMapView` is to start?

Comment: @trojanfoe the AMap3DMap - 3D Map SDK for iOS by Autonavi.

Comment: @op you got the right pod, right? not AMap2dMap but 3d. Can you add your Podfile plz?

Comment: @Daij-Djan   platform :ios, '7.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry.git'

target 'test' do
    pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.6.3'
    pod 'AMap3DMap', '~> 3.3.1'
end

Comment: @Daij-Djan  i can use the map , but just can't see the indoor map.